# Eliminate unchecked warning: cast String to T

Tags: java, generics, casting

Following method which returns a list with a dynamic type parameter:

```
public List<T> getDataList() throws SQLException {
  List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
  l.add((T) "Test");
  return l;
}
```

This gives me an unchecked cast warning.

If I change the code to:

```
public List<T> getDataList() throws SQLException {
  List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
  l.add("Test");
  (List<T>) return l;
}
```

it is nearly the same. I get a unchecked cast warning.

**Question:**

Is it possible to eliminate this unchecked warning without loosing flexibility of getDataList method?

Comment: If `T` is always `String` then why was the class generified at all?

Comment: Because it implements an interface public List<T> getDataList() throws SQLException;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public MyClass implements DataListInterface<String>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the warning is very appropriate in this situation.

Consider your method containing the generic type, its really not so generic since it would only work for a type argument of `String`.

```
public class Generic<T> {

    public List<T> getDataList() throws SQLException {
          List<T> l = new ArrayList<T>();
          l.add((T) "Test");
          return l;
        }
}
```

If I were to execute:

```
   Generic<Integer> generic = new Generic<Integer>();
```

A `ClassCastException` will be thrown appropriately since the code will attempt to cast an `Integer` to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly it is highly risky doing any of the above.

Doing `l.add((T) "Test");` will not throw `ClassCastException` iff the type `T` is `String`. In that case, once could directly just return `List<String>` because for anything else an Exception will be thrown.

And if you are trying to protect the warning by `@SuppressWarning` then it is only a time-off for a bomb that will occur later. Warnings are thrown for a reason.

You can solve it by

```
class Whatever implements SomeInterface<String>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using it like this. (Modified your second approach)

```
public  <T> List<T> getDataList() throws SQLException {
          List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
          l.add("Test");
           return (List<T>)l;
        }
```